# unable to change logging level in rxloggerlevel

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, roscore, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I recently installed fuerte and have been having problems with stopping all the DEBUG logging message from slowing packages such as stage to a crawl. I have tried changing the logging level using rxloggerlevel in rxconsole but this package freezes because it too prints out DEBUG messages. I also tried using the set_logger_level service call for both stage and rxconsole but the it comes back with

calum0@ubuntu:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/rosconsole/cmake$ rosservice call /stageros/set_logger_level stage WARN
ERROR: Unable to communicate with service [/stageros/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://ubuntu:48262]

I tried to follow the direction at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole to make my own configuration file and set the logging levels that way but this hasn't worked. I set the ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE environment path variable to a config.pc file containing

log4j.logger.ros.stage=WARN

This might not have worked due to a strange message I'm receiving every time I run roscore.

log4cxx: Could not read configuration file [/opt/ros/fuerte/config/rosconsole.config].

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33409/unable-to-change-logging-level-in-rxloggerlevel/) by [Roy89](https://answers.ros.org/users/2154/roy89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it may have been something to do with the old version of ros electric messing with my environment variables as I deleted both electric and fuerte and reinstalled fuerte and things seem to be working now.

---

Originally posted by [Roy89](https://answers.ros.org/users/2154/roy89/) with karma: 133 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0